# How to store this pattern in Java arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections

I want to store the below array pattern in List, I am not understanding how to implement this as it has alternate increment.

1. Increment the number by 399.
2. Increment by 1

and continue the above 2 steps for a certain length of numbers.
If someone can guide me for the logic with simple OOPs concepts

`0, 400, 401, 800, 801, 1200, 1201, 1600, 1601, 2000`

Comment: What have you tried? Seems like you just need to alternate the increment each time through the loop.

Comment: I have written to implement by 399 but how to alternate is what I can't think of

Comment: Shouldn't your list be 0, 399, 400, 799, 800...? Otherwise you're incrementing by 400, then 1.

Comment: Seems like you're new to programming, and if true, I guess everyone will agree that you should give it a though yourself and not ask for it on Stack Overflow. In the end if at all you don't find a solution yourself, you can google about alternating series and see how it's done.

Comment: How would you alternate IRL? You’d probably remember what you alternated by the previous iteration, and switch to the other one based on what you did last time.

Comment: Got it
I have answered the question, kindly have a look at the logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, this is what I wrote now, and it workds

```
int pages = 8;

    List<Integer> numArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    numArray.add(0);

    boolean incrementFlag = false;
    int i = 400;
    for (int j = 0; j < (pages-1); j++) {

        numArray.add(i);
        if (incrementFlag)
            i += 399;
        else
            i += 1;

        incrementFlag = !incrementFlag;

    }
```

Comment: Why do you add to `i`?

Comment: Glad you worked out a solution. The flag is redundant; you could just use the increment value as the flag since you can check its value, but that’s an implementation detail. You could also use a ternary op to select the value to add, but that’s another minor implementation detail. Good work.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this:

```
//add the first item outside of the loop, so that you can access the previous item within it
list.add(1)

//loop through the list in increments of 2
for (int i = 1; i < length; i += 2) {
   list.add(list.get(i - 1) + 399);
   list.add(list.get(i) + 1);
}
```